# FFMPEG two audio tracks, need to amplify English audio track only

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, volume, mkv

I have an `.mkv` video file with ITA and ENG audio tracks. ITA is the main track and I need to select ENG to listen in English. Even with full volume, I couldn't understand it properly so I used the following FFMPEG command to double the sound

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "volume=2.0" output.mkv`

But in the output file, ENG audio track is missing and only ITA is available. I am trying to double the volume of the ENG audio track and won't mind if the ITA one goes missing. Can someone help me with right FFMPEG command ? Thanks

PS: I even tried `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a:1 "volume=2.0" output-vol2x.mkv` based on a friend's suggestion without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-map 0` after your input file to allow all streams to output.